# CSS Attribute Selector: Apply class if custom attribute has value? Also, will it work in IE7+?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to use CSS Attribute Selector to apply a class to some spans, but only if they have content.  I have a custom attribute that will only have a value if the span has content: "entityvalue".  When using the CSS below, it does not apply the class to any elements, even if `entityvalue='1634'` is in the HTML.

```
.ApplicationName[entityvalue="*"]  {
                 display: inline;
                 background-image: url("../images/icon_application.PNG");
                 background-repeat: no-repeat;
                 background-position: left;
                 padding-left: 12px;
                 }
```

I tried `.ApplicationName[entityvalue!=""]` as found on some sites but apparently it's not in the CSS standards (doesn't work in Chrome) which really sucks, because `.ApplicationName[entityvalue=""]` does exactly the opposite of what I need...

Here are examples of a span/div WITH content (that should be styled) and a span/div WITHOUT content (which should NOT be styled):

```
<div class="ApplicationName Redirect" entitytype="Application" entityvalue=""></div>

<div class="ApplicationName Redirect" entitytype="Application" entityvalue="1234">Microsoft Outlook</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Omit the value part:

```
.ApplicationName[entityvalue]
```

This works with IE7+.

If you're paranoid about `entityvalue` being set to emptiness, and you don't want to include those elements:

```
.ApplicationName[entityvalue]:not([entityvalue=""])
```

This does not work with IE7+.

If you do need to cater to that, well, you have some options:

- Define an override/reset style for `.ApplicationName[entityvalue=""]`, so you have one rule with the first selector above, and another rule with this one.
- Use JavaScript to look for elements with the empty attribute and add a class which you can style.
- If you can modify server-side code to output that attribute differently, that's an even easier route to take.

Comment: That doesn't work. If I look at my HTML on the blank items, here is what I see:

  <div class="ApplicationName Redirect" entitytype="Application" entityvalue=""></div>

or <div class="ApplicationName Redirect" entitytype="Application" entityvalue></div> depending on browser...

Comment: @Scott Beeson: What is `entityvalue` supposed to mean? An empty value, or `entityvalue="entityvalue"`?

Comment: And yeah, I may have to end up doing this programmatically either when they are generated or using javascript, but I was really trying to avoid that just for convenience... I mean, since the CSS Attribute Selectors are there it would be nice to use them.  Seems like a very cool feature, if only it had a "not equal to"!!!

Comment: @Scott Beeson: Well you can simulate the `[attr!=val]` jQuery selector using `:not([attr=val])` in CSS but `:not()` has lousy browser support, and so on.

Comment: Added examples, if it helps answer your question above.

Comment: @Scott Beeson: The elements in your edit can be filtered using my second selector, but which browser shows you `<div ... entityvalue>` in the HTML?

Comment: actually upon further investigation it only looks like that in Chrome's debugger.  If you right-click and copy the line, it shows entityvalue="".  Not sure why it displays like that...

Comment: Okay I ended up just doing .ApplicationName[entityvalue=""]  {display: none;}

:)

Comment: So I'm no SO pro, any recommendations on how to proceed?  Technically, you're answer isn't the solution I want, and my previous comment is a good solution, but doesn't directly answer my question (plus I don't really want to self-answer)...

Comment: You could leave it as is, and see if anyone comes up with something better later on.