# How to style CSS role

Tags: css

In the following HTML

```
<div id="content" role="main">
```

the id can be accessed through `#content` in CSS. How do I access `role="main"`.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Use CSS attribute selectors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors

e.g.:

```
div[role=main]
```

Answer (score 29):

The shortest way to write a selector that accesses that specific div is to simply use

```
[role=main] {
  /* CSS goes here */
}
```

The previous answers are not wrong, but they rely on you using either a div or using the specific id. With this selector, you'll be able to have all kinds of crazy markup and it would still work and you avoid problems with specificity.

```css
[role=main] {
  background: rgba(48, 96, 144, 0.2);
}
div,
span {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" role="main">
  <span role="main">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

Accessing it like this should work: `#content[role="main"]`

Answer (score 17):

Sure you can do in this mode:

```css
 #content[role="main"]{
       //style
    }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors

Answer (score 6):

we can use

```
 element[role="ourRole"] {
    requried style !important; /*for overriding the old css styles */
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

follow this thread for more information

[CSS Attribute Selector: Apply class if custom attribute has value? Also, will it work in IE7+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416369/css-attribute-selector-apply-class-if-custom-attribute-has-value-also-will-it)

and learn css attribute selector

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2):

please use :

```
 #content[role=main]{
   your style here
}
```