# How to add display:none for custom attribute

Tags: css

I have added one custom attribute for my input.How can I add `display:none` for this custom attribute?because this is not a class or id.

```
<input type="text" myAttr="cusAttr">
```

Comment: add this css:

input[myAttr="cusAttr"]{
display:none;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Attribute Selector: Apply class if custom attribute has value? Also, will it work in IE7+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416369/css-attribute-selector-apply-class-if-custom-attribute-has-value-also-will-it)

Comment: have you tried to google it before posting this question? if not, can you please have a look at this URL, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416369/css-attribute-selector-apply-class-if-custom-attribute-has-value-also-will-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the CSS Attribute Selector.

> **CSS [attribute="value"] Selector**
>
> The [attribute="value"] selector is used to select elements with a specified attribute and value.

Try this:

```
input[myAttr="cusAttr"]{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: if i give like this `<section  myAttr="cusAttr"></section>` what would be the solution?  `section[myAttr="cusAttr"]{display:none;}` is this correct?

Comment: Just replace `input` with `section`.

Comment: If not, you can simple try this selector: `[myAttr*="cusAttr"]`. This will hide all elements with `myAttr` attribute value containing `cusAttr`.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

for this

```
<section myAttr="cusAttr"></section>
```

CSS would be

```
[myAttr~="cusAttr"]{
    display : none;
}
```

In case of Input

```
<input type="text" myAttr="cusAttr">
```

CSS

```
[myAttr="cusAttr"]{
    display:none;
}
```

This will select all the elements which has property myAttr with value cusAttr

But if you want to be more specific then

```
input[myAttr~="cusAttr"]{
    display : none;
}
```

and

```
section[myAttr="cusAttr"]{
    display:none;
}
```

are more specific

Comment: can I use `.not` like this  `.not[myAttr~="cusAttr"]`

Comment: Yes, you can use any psedo class with this